# Two TP-Link routers are connected

Tags: router, subnet

I have two TP-Link routers: one is connected to the ISP and the other's WAN is connected to one of my Ethernet ports (assigned IP from router1 192.168.1.200). Hosts in the second router (192.168.0.0/24) can ping hosts on the first router but not the other way around).

I added a static route from router1 to the network 192.168.0.0/24.

Comment: So, what is your question? (And why are you connecting a router's WAN port to a local machine?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your routers are performing [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on traffic going from their LAN interfaces to their WAN interface. If you disable NAT on the second router, your problem will most likely be solved. If the option is not included in the manufacturer's firmware, you might want to check if your devices are [compatible with DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.ca/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices).

Here's what happens when a Device 2 connected behind Router 2 pings a Device 1 behind Router 1:

1. **Device 2** issues an ICMP echo request to the destination of **Device 1**. Since it doesn't know any specific route to 192.168.1.0/24, it sends it to its default gateway: **router 2**.
2. **Router 2** receives the packet from **Device 2**. It performs Network Address Translation (Port Translation), so that the packet sent to **Device 1** seems to come from the router itself, on a randomly selected port. For instance, the packet will seem to come from **Router 2**, port 12345.
3. **Device 1** will receive the packet from **Router 2** and see that the source IP is **Router 2**'s, and the source port is 12345. It will then answer the request.
4. **Router 2** receives the answer and knows that everything going on port 12345 should be sent to **Device 2** since it has an entry in its translation table.

[image: Topology]

EDIT: If you simply want to extend a network, you might want to consider giving **Router 2** a static IP address in the same subnet as **Router 1** (for instance: 192.168.1.253), and connecting a LAN port on **Router 2** to a LAN port on **Router 1**. You would simply not use the WAN port on **Router 2**.

Comment: I'll try it sir and will get back to you. Thanks a lot for your professional response.

Comment: Sir, I was unable to set a static ip for the ethernet port, sorry for the bothering, I really want to learn, but I don't have the expertise, so can you detail more, from which router should i assign the static ip, can you write the whole scenario? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Basically, you would open up the Web interface of **Router 2** and assign it a static IP address (for instance: 192.168.1.253) on its LAN interface. I don't know how to do that on your particular router model, but [this](http://www.tp-link.com/ca/article/?id=67) is a tutorial on how to do it on one of the TP-Link models. Once you set that, you hook a cable from one of the LAN ports on **Router 1** to another LAN port on **Router 2**. Your networks will then be bridged together. Do not use the WAN port on **Router 2** in that setup.

Comment: Aha I see, then all other devices on Router2 will be assigned by Router1's DHCP server, no?!

Comment: Yes, indeed. You've got a point though: you should only enable one of both DHCP servers in that case.